# Problems after mapping Alt_R to Control

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb

I have mapped by `Alt_R` to `Control`. My `Control_R` is also mapped to `Control`. `Alt_L` remains as `Alt` (`Mod1`).

I used `xkbcomp :0 keyboard.xkb` to dump the current configuration file. In that file, in the `xkb_symbols` section, in the place of `modifier_map Mod1 { <RALT> };` I put `modifier_map Control { <RALT> }` and then used the edited .xkb file with `xkbcomp keyboard.xkb :0`.

Now as expected `Alt_R + x` and `Alt_R +f` work (I'm testing all these in Emacs).

But `Alt_R + Alt_L + F` (which is supposed to be `Control + Alt + F`) doesn't work whereas `Alt_R + Alt_L + B` (supposed to be `Control + Alt + B`) works.

I tried using `xev` to test what is happening but `xev` doesn't even receive the combination `Alt_R + Alt_L +F` but it receives `Control_R + Alt_L + F` and in the latter case output is nothing that's not to be expected.

What might be the reasons for this weird behavior? Or are there any tools that can be used to diagnose the issue?

EDIT:

Entire configuration file dumped with `xkbcomp :0 keyboard.xkb` after editing : [configuration file](http://pastebin.com/6preX0iJ)

Comment: Changing modifiers is more complicated than that, you have to keep modifier declarations consistent with keysym declarations. I think you need to change something else, but I'm not familiar enough with XKB to know what.

Comment: @Gilles I thought about that too. But it would still not explain the strange asymmetry between `F` and `B` keys.

Comment: Forgot to ask: what keyboard layout and options are you starting from? In particular, is it one where right Alt is Alt or AltGr?

Comment: I think right Alt is Alt. Although there is a virtual modifier AltGr.  I put a link to the current keyboard configuration file. See the edited question